# Why is my override not working?

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I've been trying to create an override for the `addto.phtml` file but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have this theme file:

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/product/view/addto.phtml

With this in the file:

```
<div class="product-addto-links" data-role="add-to-links">
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>

    <a href="#amfinder.product.attributes" class="action">
        <span>View Compatibility</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I've run:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$ php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Everything was a-ok but refreshing the product view page had no changes. What am I missing from my override?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the custom theme? (settings in the backoffice)

Comment: @ArnoVandeCappelle I am sure indeedy

Comment: ^^flagging own question due to typo issue

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of last comment ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have put your file in the wrong place.

Instead of:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/product/view/addto.phtml
```

you should put the file in:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addto.phtml
```

Notice the **`templates`** in the file path.